# Does "lebensspendend" (with double s) officially exist?

Tags: compound

My dictionary says "lebenspendend" and "Leben spendend" but I cannot find *lebensspendend* double s compound. I suppose it's not a variant.

Comment: And not to confuse it with *lebendspendend* (donating while alive)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  Likewise we should not confuse *lebendgebährend* with *lebensgebährend* although the one and the other usually occur in combination.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @infinitezero already said [DWDS lists lebensspendend](https://www.dwds.de/wb/lebensspendend) as a variant of lebenspendend, so you may say it has the same meaning.

But it gets interesting, when you take a look at Google's ngram Viewer, which displays a graph showing how those words have occurred in a corpus of books.

[image]

[source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lebensspendend%2Clebenspendend&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clebensspendend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clebenspendend%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clebensspendend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clebenspendend%3B%2Cc0)

As you can see since the 1980's the variant seems to be more common than the original.

Answer (score 3):

*Duden* does not list the word, however [DWDS does list](https://www.dwds.de/wb/lebensspendend) it as a *Nebenform* (variant).

Answer (score 2):

The question asked was actually:

**Can *lebenspendend* also be spelled *lebensspendend*, i.e. with an additional s?**

To answer this: there is no final rule-based answer. The writer is at liberty to write it either way. For my taste, *lebenspendend* would be slightly more poetic, *lebensspendend* sligtly more prosaic.

As for the productivity of suffigations with *-spendend*: you can glue it to other substantives with suitable meaming as it pleases you:

- wasserspendend
- freudespendend
- raumspendend
- genussspendend
- labungspendend
- heiterkeitspendend
- duftspendend
- samenspendend

and so on. (I am sure most of them will not be registered in dictionariesm but this does not make them invalid or inexisting.)

Most of them would be spelled without an additional "s". An "s" could be added, though, to *labungsspendend* and *heiterkeitsspendend*. Which leads to the question: when can "s" be added, and when not? I suppose there is some complicated rule, but at the moment I am not able to present it.

Comment: see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut#Weitere_Aspekte_der_Verwendung_von_Fugenelementen

Answer (score 1):

You just used the word *lebensspendend*, so: here it is! You used it, so it exists.

The goal of each language is to transport ideas. If a speaker/writer uses a certain word, and if the listener/reader has a high change to guess which idea was in the speakers/writers mind when he/she used this word, then the word not just only exists, but it even does its job: It transports an idea.

There is nothing like an official bureau that can say that one word exists, and another doesn't. There are just editorial departments who collect and list words that are more or less often used. But sometimes they list old and outdated words, that no longer are in use (but still exist), while they fail to list brandnew (but also existing) words.

Comment: I think this is better suited as a comment. OP's question is not about the physical existence but about the validity. So while it may be poorly worded, I think this answer is a little too nitpicky

Comment: Please roll back, if you consider my edit enchroaing.

Comment: Did you ever play Scrabble..?

Comment: Welsche Schuhle vertit den dihse Annsicht?

Comment: @userunknown [Descriptivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_description), as opposed to [Prescriptivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription). While the first is very useful in research, the latter is useful in school. Hubert Schölnast often has a descrptive PoV and not always sees that the latter PoV has its merits as well.

Answer (score -1):

Since the question of *officially existence* is not answerable without a definition of *official* regarding the use of a language, 
I consider your question being meant in the way of:

> Would the word *leben**s**spendend* be considered valid German?

Even though [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/lebensspendend) lists *lebensspendend* as by-form of *lebenspendend*, I think there is a comprehensible reason why [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Leben_spendend) doesn't.

DUDEN recomments the spelling *Leben spendend* and actually that's the meaning of *lebenspendend* - *live-giving*.

If something *spendet Leben*, it is *lebenspendend*. If people are donating blood, they are *blutspendend*, ...

I have no idea, why there should be an additional *s* at the end of *Leben*. I think, nobody would ever say *blut**s**spendend*. It just doesn't make sense whatsoever.

So I think, that's a (according to @mtwde's post **common**) mistake arising from the structural resemblance to the word *lebenserhaltend*.

But *lebenserhaltend* is a different story.

- *Lebenserhaltende Maßnahmen* (life support measures) are *Maßnahmen zur Erhaltung des Lebens*.
- *Lebenserhaltende Funktionen* (life support functions) are *für die Erhaltung des Lebens notwendige Funktionen*.

So there is a genitive in there justifying the additional *s*.

That doesn't apply for *lebenspendend* and therefore imho <s>*leben**s**spendend*</s> is simply wrong.

Comment: The *‑s‑* is a [Fugenmorphem](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) and not a genitive, as can be seen from compounds such as *arbeitserleichternd, ‑ersparend, ‑erschwerend*, where the first part is feminine.

Comment: @DavidVogt from your given source: *Das Vorderwort erscheint in der Genitiv­form*

Comment: *Arbeit* is feminine. Its genitive is *Arbeit*.

Comment: @DavidVogt O really? Yes it's called Fugenlaut or Fugenmorphem. So what? In *lebenserhaltend* it's not there for easier pronunciation or whatever but imo because of the genitive. Proof me wrong!

Comment: A genitive would occur consistently. *Fugenlaute* are pretty unpredictable: Duden has [lebensprühend](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lebenspruehend) but not [lebenssprühend](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lebensspruehend); has both [lebenverneinend](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lebenverneinend) and [lebensverneinend](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lebensverneinend); and only [lebensbedrohend](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lebensbedrohend) but not [lebenbedrohend](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lebenbedrohend).

Comment: @DavidVogt You bring on examples that have nothing to do with mine and then discuss that what I say is wrong for your examples? Fugenlaute are pretty unpredictable but if it's for genitive it would occur consistently? Not very convincing. Enjoy your downvote.

Comment: your own example contradicts you. whats the difference between lebensspendend and lebenserhaltend? das eine spendet Leben, das andere erhaltet Leben.

Comment: @ths In *lebenspendendes X* ist X Ursache von *Leben*. In *lebenserhaltendes X* ist X das Mittel zum Zweck der *Erhaltung des Lebens* - zwei völlig verschiedene Zusammenhänge.